# how can i show css animation in my html using flask?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

im a begginer here , struggling with basic stuff

I have my flask:

```
from flask import Flask , render_template , send_file , send_from_directory 

import os
app = Flask(__name__)

#PRIMERA FUNCION
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return  render_template('prueba.html')
```

and i have my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - The Arrow</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="arrow-1"></div>

<!-- partial -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

when I open the html file on browser it shows the css ,
but when I run flask css doesnt show and I cant figure out why!!!

I have try this

```
@app.route('/css/<path:filename>')
def css_file(filename):
    file_path = os.path.join('css', filename)
    return send_file(file_path)
```

and i also thought it was a problem of my folder layout but I already tried re arrange folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask has different ways to do this, but the convention is to put static assets (like CSS) in the `static` directory (which should be at the root of your project) and link them in with Jinja and the `url_for()` function. so in your case it would look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - The Arrow</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
```

More explained in the [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/static/)